# Nightmare JS use .evaluate return variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, screen-scraping, nightmare

I'm new to Javascript, Node.js, and Nightmare. I'm trying to add a feature to count the number of titles on a page and then wait until the total number of titles increases by 5.

Here is the snippet:

```
.evaluate(function () {
    var elements = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('title'));
    var firstCount = elements.length;
    var higherCount = firstCount + 5;
    var selector = '\'#price' + higherCount + '\'';
    return selector;
})
.wait(selector)
```

When I run I get the error:

> .wait(selector)
>   ^ ReferenceError: selector is not defined at Object.

How do I get the variable `selector` to the `.wait` command?

Comment: I gave up on Nightmare and switched to Puppeteer. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs, the function evaluate passes the return value from the function on to the caller.

http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/evaluate.html

so in your example, the call would be

```
var selector = page.evaluate(function () {
    var elements = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('title'));
    var firstCount = elements.length;
    var higherCount = firstCount + 5;
    var selector = '\'#price' + higherCount + '\'';
    return selector;
});
```

If for some reason the contents of the evaluate call are asyncronous, you could return a promise;

```
page.evaluate(function () {

    return new Promise( function(success, error) {
        // whatever is the async thing
        success(value);
        // or if there is an error
        error("details of error");
    }

}).then( function (results) {
    // we have our results
}).catch( function(err) { 
    // ... oops
});
```

This might then be compatible with async / await, depending on the context.

Comment: Thanks for the response gburton but it didn't solve the problem. Maybe someone with NightmareJS experience will respond.

Answer (score 0):

You can add something to your Selector html and target it with wait() assuming your Selector is an html element. Something like this.

```
.evaluate(function () {
    var selector = document.getElementById("demo");
    selector.className += " waitForThis";
})
.wait(".waitForThis")
```

I don't think you can use evaluate's return value for wait() though.